# Ignore newlines with diff

Tags: unix, diff

I'd like to ignore newlines when I compare c source files. For example I want following two codes are reported they are same.

```
// codeA
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

// codeB
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

I already have tried following options but could not get the result.

```
diff -b codeA codeB
diff -w codeA codeB
```

Comment: Yes, "-B" also reports they are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pretty print both files using, for example, GNU Indent, http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/ , and then compare them with diff.

Answer (score 7):

There is a tool called "word diff" (tool command line must be 'wdiff') which might help. http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html

Comment: Is there a good tool for visualizing the output of wdiff?  In particular, it would be nice if they color-coded the differences

Comment: there is another option which is to use: git diff --color-words if applicable

Comment: @nukeguy it's ironic that you put that comment right under the link to the manual which includes a colored output example http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html#wdiff-Examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want an all or nothing answer you can first strip the files of newlines:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '\n' > stripped.txt
```

This is of course very unhelpful for finding actual differences.