# How to use wdiff view the difference between two files while ignoring whitespace including newlines?

Tags: file, diff, difference

I reviewed the manual for "diff" and it says:

> For many other programs newline is also a white space character, but
>   diff is a line-oriented program and a newline character always ends a
>   line. Hence the -w or --ignore-all-space option does not ignore
>   newline-related changes; it ignores only other white space changes.

wdiff seems to be recommended from this answer: [Ignore newlines with diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192890/ignore-newlines-with-diff)

but I can't find the right arguments in the man page of wdiff.

Comment: By default, a file "A", containing `1     2      3` will compare as "NOT EQUAL" to a file B with `1 2 3`.  However,  `diff -w A B` will compare as "EQUAL".  Q: what exactly is it you want to do, that "diff -w" doesn't already do for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore newlines with diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192890/ignore-newlines-with-diff)

Comment: I couldn't find ignore newline arguments in wdiff, and it is not code I'm comparing so indent won't help

Comment: @paulsm4 `wdiff` does not have an option `-w` to ignore whitespace changes. OP and I would like to diff two files, ignoring whitespace differences and only highlighting the changes on a word-by-word, not line-by-line basis. This is especially useful if there are long lines with small changes.

Comment: For code files (or other files which can be "normalised"), this answer from [Ignore newlines with diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13192954/2445204) is helpful: Normalise both files first, then run `wdiff`